# use of unresolved identifier (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, identifier

I am receiving an error when trying to run my project in Xcode. For some reason the "userid" function won't build and I am fairly new to programming so I have no clue as to how to make this work. In simple, the line that's giving me an error is supposed to allow a user to log into their instagram acccount to use the application. I am getting an error that reads

> use of unresolved identifier "userID"

Here is my code:

```
      if (result.result.isSuccess) {
      let json = JSON(result.result.value!)

      if (self.loginType == .Instagram) {
        if let accessToken = json["access_token"].string, _ = json["user"]["id"].string {
          print("Logged into Instagram")
          let user = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.context) as! User
          user.userID = userID
          user.accessToken = accessToken
          user.placesType = "Establishment"
          user.uberAccessToken = ""
          self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToMapView", sender: ["user": user])
        }
      } else if (self.loginType == .Uber) {
        if let accessToken = json["access_token"].string {
          print("Logged into Uber")
          if let fetchRequest = self.coreDataStack.model.fetchRequestTemplateForName("UserFetchRequest") {
            do {
              let results = try self.coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [User]
              let user = results.first!
              user.uberAccessToken = accessToken
              user.uberAccessTokenExpiryDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval((60 * 60 * 24) * 30)
              user.uberMostRecentRequestID = ""
              self.coreDataStack.saveContext()
              self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToUberView", sender: ["user": user])
            } catch {
              self.showAlertWithMessage("Please try again!", title: "Couln't Fetch User", button: "Ok")
              print("Couldn't fetch user")
              self.close()
```

Comment: where should userID come from? you nowhere define it

Comment: I would assume you need to do `let userID = json["user"]["id"].string` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Replace the underscore character with `userID`

Comment: @vadian which underscore am I replacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with

```
if let accessToken = json["access_token"].string, _ = json["user"]["id"].string {
```

You are assigning the user id to `_` instead of `userID`.
Try this:

```
if let accessToken = json["access_token"].string, userID = json["user"]["id"].string {
```

Comment: that worked so the app builds but it crashes each time I enter in my login info so I'm looking to see what the issue is now, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: If you have a new question, feel free to ask a new question; include the console log and the relevant code. Look out for optionals that are force-unwrapped;)

Comment: Ok thanks! This platform is really sensitive when it comes to questions and how theyre "supposed" to be asked, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes it is:) yet I didn't want to link you to [ask] but to the 'ask question' button. [ask] is still a good and recommended read anyway;)

Comment: Oh, and by the way, if this answers your question, feel free to accept the answer:)